Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number
I am having a error in my register.php page code while inserting a query statement. my php code in register file is as follows:
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"lms");
    $query = "insert into users values(null,'$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[
    password]','$_POST[mobile]','$_POST[address]')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Registration successfully.... You may login now.")
    window.location.href = "login.php";
</script>


The following error is showing in the "insert query in the above code".
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\wamp64\www\practice\register.php on line 4
I am using Wamp server on my laptop.
I expected to register user into my database in mysql. But it is showing the following error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\wamp64\www\practice\register.php on line 4
